# Can I split the AdGroup budgets down to specific Ads in Twitter Ads?

Tags: twitter

If I am running a Twitter Ads campaign and have two ads under one AdGroup, is there any way of splitting the budget for the two ads in the AdGroup? Or does Twitter do this automatically.

I know I can split campaign budgets across different AdGroups in a campaign, but wasn't sure if I can also divide the AdGroup budget down amongst ads (there doesn't seem to be anyway of doing this)?

Any help / answers would be wonderful.

Emily

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.  There currently does appear to be a Stack Exchange community for this question.  You should contact Twitter directly with any specific questions about advertising with them.

Comment: @Ramhound I think actually it might be covered in the StackOverflow Web Applications forum - as an admin can you transfer the question to that site?

Comment: I am not an Administrator.  I am not a moderator.  I do not believe this question is within scope at Web Applications SE.  This question is about a specific advertising policy specific to Twitter.

Comment: @ramhound It's not about policy it's about the application. I'll delete off this site and post it on that site and see if anyone answers.

Comment: You should wait until the question is closed, I voted to close, if others disagree and vote to migrate the question it saves you the trouble.  If you submit the question again, it makes it impossible, to migrate this questions.  Deleting the question should be avoided.